# Jira logwork screen extension - custom javascript code when log work is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira, jira-plugin

Is it possible to extend somehow logwork screen in Jira 4.3.3 in order to run custom javascript code when the log button is clicked? I would like to append some custom text to comment text. I don't want to create jira plugin I would like to edit only logwork.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify the view if you like but I'd highly recommend against it.  You will need to preserve or re-do entirely your changes every time you update Jira.  It's more work up front but a plugin really is the best route.

Comment: What kind of plugin should I create for this use case?

Comment: Look into event listeners:

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Writing+JIRA+Event+Listeners+with+the+atlassian-event+Library

You should be able to listen to an event when a worklog is created.